# Why do independent Tcl interpreters executing Tcl_ExprDouble in parallel require a mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcl, mutex

I have written a simple class that wraps a callback in Tcl. It manages its own Tcl interpreter and store the Tcl command as a string. The `go` method feeds the string to the interpreter and returns the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <tcl.h>

class Tcl_callback {
  std::string callback;
  Tcl_Interp *local_interp;

 public:  
  Tcl_callback(std::string c): 
    callback(std::move(c)),
    local_interp(Tcl_CreateInterp()) 
    {}

  ~Tcl_callback() {Tcl_DeleteInterp(local_interp);}

  Tcl_callback(const Tcl_callback & c):
    callback(c.callback),
    local_interp(Tcl_CreateInterp()) {}

  double go() {
    std::cout << "going..." << std::endl;
    double resultValue;
    int resultCode;
    resultCode = Tcl_ExprDouble(local_interp, callback.c_str(), &resultValue);
    if (resultCode != TCL_OK) {
      throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: failed evaluation of the expression: \"" + callback + "\"\n  " + Tcl_GetStringResult(local_interp));
    }
    return resultValue;
  }
};
```

I have tested it with a simple main that allows to switch between parallel and serial execution:

```
#define PARALLEL

int main() {
  const int n_callbacks = 100;
  const int n_iter = 10;

  std::vector<Tcl_callback> cs(n_callbacks, Tcl_callback("sqrt(123)"));

  for (int i = 0; i < n_iter; i++) {
  #ifdef PARALLEL
    std::vector<std::future<double>> fs;
    for (auto & c: cs) {
      fs.push_back( std::async(std::launch::async,[&](){return c.go();}) );
    }
    for (auto & f: fs) {
      std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
    }
  #else
    for (auto & c: cs) {
      std::cout << c.go() << std::endl;
    }
  #endif
  }

  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Although all the `Tcl_callback` objects look independent, I have not been able to obtain a stable parallel version without protecting the `go` method with a global mutex:

```
std::mutex m; //at global scope
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m); //inside the go method
```

I would like to understand the reason for this and possible ways to improve the code.

Comment: This surprises me. What version of Tcl is this? (We're supposed to have locks already for the few small bits of shared global state.)

Comment: @DonalFellows 8.6.4 Have you been able to reproduce it? I compiled the code with `g++ -std=c++14 -ltcl -pthread async-tcl.cpp` (gcc 4.9.2)

Comment: Yes, was busy writing up the fix. :-D Note that while it's the fix, it'll still need quite a bit more work on your behalf to make it more like what you started with. The key point is that **Tcl interpreters are bound to their thread**; that's what you were violating. (I ought to check if the documentation makes that explicit.)

Comment: The documentation for `Tcl_CreateInterp` is entirely explicit. Updated my answer with the relevant two sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a `Tcl_Interp` should only be accessed (e.g., via `Tcl_ExprDouble` or `Tcl_DeleteInterp`) from the thread that created it; the implementation of Tcl's interpreters uses thread-local variables heavily to avoid holding a global lock. Unfortunately, you're creating the interpreters prior to firing off all the threads, causing the interpreters to be taken across threads, which won't work.

From the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/CrtInterp.htm)…

> The token returned by **Tcl_CreateInterp** may only be passed to Tcl routines called from the same thread as the original **Tcl_CreateInterp** call. It is not safe for multiple threads to pass the same token to Tcl's routines.

Changing the code to this (where the `Tcl_Interp` is local in scope to the `go` method):

```
class Tcl_callback {
  std::string callback;

 public:
  Tcl_callback(std::string c):
    callback(std::move(c))
    {}

  ~Tcl_callback() {}

  Tcl_callback(const Tcl_callback & c):
    callback(c.callback) {}

  double go() {
    std::cout << "going..." << std::endl;
    double resultValue;
    int resultCode;
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    resultCode = Tcl_ExprDouble(interp, callback.c_str(), &resultValue);
    if (resultCode != TCL_OK) {
      throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: failed evaluation of the expression: \"" + callback + "\"\n  " + Tcl_GetStringResult(interp));
    }
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    return resultValue;
  }
};
```

Which is less efficient will make it work (or at least it works when I try it). I'll let you figure out how to use a clever way to avoid creating *quite* so many interpreters! (I'll also let you clean up the potential resource leak in the throw-an-exception case. This is proof-of-concept code only.)

Comment: Oh.. I think I've seen that piece of documentation before. I also tried to create the interpreter in the `go` function before (in the real code) it worked but that was too much overhead (much more than with the global lock). So even if I got some (apparentely) working code with the global lock, that is still incorrect, right?

Comment: As I said, the implementations use thread-specific data. You really _really_ can't dodge the requirement to be thread-strict. You could probably create some sort of map from (current) thread ID to Tcl_Interp which you populate as necessary, and have your worker threads get the interp handle from that, while setting up a thread-exit handler to delete the interpreter when the thread goes away (Tcl's got an API to help with that, `Tcl_CreateThreadExitHandler`). Ugh, that's quite complicated.

Comment: I adopted the idea of the map but I implemented it in a thread pool. At the beginning of the thread working function I allocate the interpreter, so each thread sets up its one. Then I query the pool with the current thread id to obtain the right one. It is relatively simple, self-contained and with very good performances. Thank you again for your helpful suggestions!